# Insert row below based on the column value using google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I stuck with this. Seems easy at first then I got lost!

What I am aiming for:

- to insert a row(s) based on a cell value (Col C) -- insert row(s) below
- after a new row(s) is inserted, copy the data from previous row + string value from previous row, removing that value as well from the previous row.

[image]

I am trying to use this formula but I got lost...

```
function addRows(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var dataRange = sheet1.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i<dataValues.length; i++) {
    for (var j= 0; j<dataValues.length; i++) {
      /* If blank or 0 - zero, skip */
      if (dataValues[i][3] == "" || dataValues[i][3]== 0) {continue;}
      /* If value is >=1, insert new row(s) below the active row */
      if (dataValues[i][3] >=1) { 
      sheet1.insertRowAfter(i);
      sheet1.getRange(...) // copy the data from previous + string  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In order to help to think of your goal, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect?

Comment: Here's a sample sheet - sheet6. I also updated the picture above, the "Datas" column had an incorrect text. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xznoTAH2yS-Xnf-b3cCc0j8vxa9jS10WP1HjQapzNw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample Spreadsheet. Where can I see the input and output you expect? You want to convert "A2:B2" to "A6:B11" in "Sheet6"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The output I am hoping for is A6:B11.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your shared Spreadsheet, you want to convert from the values of "A2:B3" to the values of "A6:B11".
- In your shared image, you want to achieve as follows.

  - From

    ```
    Data1   A0HD, B0DP
    Data2   C12X, D0B1, E2C1, F6H1
    ```
  - To

    ```
    Data1   A0HD
    Data1   B0DP
    Data2   C12X
    Data2   D0B1
    Data2   E2C1
    Data2   F6H1
    ```
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample script:

In order to test the script, please use the following script to your shared Spreadsheet. And run the script.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceSheetName = "Sheet6";
  var destinationSheetName = "Sheet6";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);

  // Retrieve source values.
  var values = sheet.getRange("A2:B3").getValues();

  // Convert values.
  var result = values.reduce(function(ar, [a, b]) {
    var temp = b.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
      ar.push([a, temp[i].trim()]);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Put values.
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

- In above script, when the script is run, the values of "A2:B3" from the "Sheet6" are retrieved and the converted values are put to the last row of "Sheet6".
- If only input values are put to the source sheet, you can also use `var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();` instead of `var values = sheet.getRange("A2:B3").getValues();`.

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, your script worked. Quick question, what does "ar' mean on this "function(ar, [a, b]"? I wanted to ensure I understand what it is and how it is being used.

Comment: @JMR Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, `ar` and `[a, b]` are [Accumulator and Current Value of reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), respectively. And [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is used to "Current Value".